# replace all occurrences in a datatable with a value in another data table

Tags: c#, datatable

is there any way to replace all occurrences of a value in a data table with another value from a different data table.for example I have two data table one has Itemid and another has itemid and item name.I need to replace item id in first data table with the item name from the second data table..Is there any possible way to replace all occurances at one go or should i go for the usual loop method and use Datatable.Select method.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Marco am using a MS-SQL database the First data table is from excel file which i ll be getting in daily basis.Second data table is from a SQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? (I realise it is a loop - but very compact and any built in method would loop anyway, just behind the scenes)

```
        //Build first Test DT
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("itemID", typeof(string));

        //Build Second Test DT
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("itemID", typeof(string));
        dt2.Columns.Add("itemName", typeof(string));

        //aad 3 DataRows to first DT - ID only
        DataRow dt1_1 = dt1.NewRow();
        dt1_1["itemID"] = "1";

        DataRow dt1_2 = dt1.NewRow();
        dt1_2["itemID"] = "2";

        DataRow dt1_3 = dt1.NewRow();
        dt1_3["itemID"] = "3";

        dt1.Rows.Add(dt1_1);
        dt1.Rows.Add(dt1_2);
        dt1.Rows.Add(dt1_3);

        //aad 3 DataRows to first DT - ID & Name
        DataRow dt2_1 = dt2.NewRow();
        dt2_1["itemID"] = "1";
        dt2_1["itemName"] = "ItemOne";

        DataRow dt2_2 = dt2.NewRow();
        dt2_2["itemID"] = "2";
        dt2_2["itemName"] = "ItemTwo";

        DataRow dt2_3 = dt2.NewRow();
        dt2_3["itemID"] = "3";
        dt2_3["itemName"] = "ItemThree";

        dt2.Rows.Add(dt2_1);
        dt2.Rows.Add(dt2_2);
        dt2.Rows.Add(dt2_3);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //replacing code - quite comact - assumed itemId is PK//
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
        {
                string strSelect = "[itemID] = '"+ dr["itemID"] +"'";
                DataRow[] myRow = dt2.Select(strSelect);
                if (myRow.Length == 1)
                {
                    dr["itemID"] = myRow[0]["itemName"];
                }
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //dt1 now has itemOne, itemTwo and itemThree instead of 1, 2, 3//
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL I would try:

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2
SET t1.itemid = t2.itemname
WHERE t1.itemid = t2.itemid
```

With MS-SQL I would try

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.itemid = t2.itemname
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.itemid = t2.itemid
```